# jQuery CSS hover using variable

Tags: jquery, css, variables, background

How can I pass a previously captured variable into a background property using jQuery? I'm working with a very large table, a lot of cells and a lot of data. There are multiple colors being used, being applied to the table rather than the cell (with good reason).

Here is my code (greatly condensed HTML)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="nonLevel"><ul class="list"><li>text to go here</li></ul></td>
        <td class="block"><a href="#"><ul class="list"><li>text to go here</li></ul></a></td>
        <td class="block"><a href="#"><ul class="list"><li>text to go here</li></ul></td>
        <td class="block"><a href="#"><ul class="list"><li>text to go here</li></ul></a></td>
        <td class="block"><a href="#"><ul class="list"><li>text to go here</li></ul></a></td>
        <td class="block"><a href="#"><ul class="list"><li>text to go here</li></ul></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>


$(".block").hover(function () {
    var myColor = $(this).css("background-color");

    $(this).css({'background-color' : 'yellow'});
    }, function () {
        var cssObj = {
            'background-color' : myColor,
        }
        $(this).css(cssObj);
    });
```

So I'm trying to capture the original color on rollover (which works when I pass the `myColor` variable into an alert), then change the color to yellow and then on rollout switch back to 'myColor'.

I've looked at `addClasss` and `removeClass`, but they don't seem to cut it in terms of how this is set up. Again, the background color is set in CSS on the table, not the cell, this can't be changed.

Comment: your missing a semi colon after this line       `var cssObj = {
      'background-color' : myColor,
      }`

Comment: Also, the extra comma at the end of `cssObj` will crash IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to store the background-color - or even use JavaScript/jQuery. You simply could use CSS:

```
.block:hover {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

If you have to use JavaScript (for example, because you need to support IE6), simply set the background-color to empty:

```
$(".block").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "");
});
```

And if you still think you need to store the color, use jQuerys data functionality:

```
$(".block").hover(function() {
    $(this).data("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", $(this).data("background-color"));
});
```

Comment: I didn't realise you could set a color to empty, works perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: +1 for css solution. But you should really don't restore data for each mouseover. Store the background-color as data once from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use jQuery data to store the original color. And then get it on mouseout.

```
$(".block").each(function (index, elem) {
    $(elem).data('orginalColor', $(elem).css("background-color"))
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : 'yellow'});
}, function () {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : $(this).data('orginalColor')});
});
```

You can read about jQuery data here: [jQuery Data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Also I would advise to use delegate instead (jQuery uses it internal in some cases for you).  This bind only one event handler for the entire table instead of one for each 'td'

```
$('.block').each(function (index, elem) { //code });
$('table').delegate('td', 'mouseover', function() { //code });
$('table').delegate('td', 'mouseout', function() { //code });
```

..fredrik

Answer (score 1):

You could stuff the existing color into a data attribute:

```
$(".block").hover(function () {
    $(this).data("bkg",$(this).css("background-color"));
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
}, function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", $(this).data("bkg"));
});
```

Comment: @Keith: see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246598/jquery-css-hover-using-variable/4246734#4246734) for the jQuery way to do it; but [RoToRa's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246598/jquery-css-hover-using-variable/4246713#4246713) is the better way to implement CSS hover effects.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this, especially if your table is large, is to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data).

```
$('.block').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (event.type === 'mouseover') {
        var myColor = $this.css('background-color');
        $this.data('myColor', myColor);
        $this.css('background-color': 'yellow');
    } else {
        $this.css('background-color', $this.data('myColor'));
    }
});
```

[Hot demo action →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/fELwX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to declare your myColor variable outside of the jQuery call.  Otherwise it should be a local variable, meaning it will go out of scope before hover is called a second time on handlerOut.